# Why OpenSSL::PKCS5.pbkdf2_hmac_sha1 generates key with different length?

Tags: ruby, pbkdf2

I'm using Rails 3.2 and are trying to generate a key and IV from **pbkdf2_hmac_sha1** function in order to crypto something using AES-CBC 256.

The code I use to generate it is:

```
require "openssl"
require "base64"
require "digest"
require "securerandom"

@chave = "fd5d148867091d7595c388ac0dc50bb465052b764c4db8b4b4c3448b52ee0b33df16975830acca82"

cipher = OpenSSL::Cipher.new("AES-256-CBC")
key_iv = OpenSSL::PKCS5.pbkdf2_hmac_sha1(@chave, salt, 2000, cipher.key_len+cipher.iv_len)
key = key_iv[0, cipher.key_len]
iv  = key_iv[cipher.key_len, cipher.iv_len]
```

I generate a random salt using SecureRandom.urlsafe_base64 and noticed that sometimes the IV length (which should be 16 bytes) is 15 bytes rather than 16 bytes when I use some salts.

For instance, if you have a salt = "lzbH78AwVK7U1eo-ephK6A", it generates a IV = "604ff394b52e79255fa35b081684b0" (15 bytes long).

Can someone have a clue of what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 2):

Since `pbkdf2_hmac_sha1` yields a string, it seems your conversion to hex-number is wrong.
(using your values in this example):

```
irb(main):029:0> iv  = key_iv[cipher.key_len, cipher.iv_len]
=> "`O\xF3\x94\n\xB5.y%_\xA3[\b\x16\x84\xB0"
irb(main):030:0> iv.length
=> 16
irb(main):032:0> iv.each_char { |c| puts c.ord.to_s(16) }
60
4f
f3
94
a     ### this one is missing in your number -- it maps to \n
b5
2e
79
25
5f
a3
5b
8
16
84
b0
=> "`O\xF3\x94\n\xB5.y%_\xA3[\b\x16\x84\xB0"
```

Comment: Thanks to answer!
I've really removed the trailing '\n' from the string but it also removed inner '\n'.